# Symfony STDIN error when install via composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, stdin

I try to install symfony via composer on Windows 7 with command

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition www1
```

And I get the error

```
[ErrorException]
Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN'
```

What do I need to do to solve this issue?

PS This is full log:

```
C:\WebServers\home\asd>composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition www1
Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.6.4)
  - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.6.4)
    Loading from cache

Created project in www1
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing twig/twig (v1.18.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.4.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.4.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.6.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.4.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sensiolabs/security-checker (v2.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v3.0.16)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.2.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/assetic-bundle (v2.6.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.12.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.7.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.3.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.3.8)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing twig/extensions (v1.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sensio/generator-bundle (v2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/lessphp (Assetic provides the integration with the lessphp LESS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp (Assetic provides the integration with the scssphp SCSS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp-compass (Assetic provides the integration with the SCSS compass plugin)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing patchwork/jsqueeze (Assetic provides the integration with the JSqueeze JavaScript compressor)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing ptachoire/cssembed (Assetic provides the integration with phpcssembed to embed data uris)
symfony/assetic-bundle suggests installing kriswallsmith/spork (to be able to dump assets in parallel)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing videlalvaro/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
Generating autoload files
Would you like to install Acme demo bundle? [y/N]


  [ErrorException]
  Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN'



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-cus
tom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

Also in got application were 3 empty files in folder "web/bundles" where must be folders of bundles with css files and images. Because of this there were no images on page "web/app_dev.php" in browser. Then I executed the command

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

and in "web/bundles" appeared images and css files and then images appeared on page "web/app_dev.php" so it displays correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This error might appear because your php is installed `CGI binary` mode, not `CLI`. A workaround for this might be putting at the top of your `AppKernel.php` file following line:

```
define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that launching composer in non-interactive mode (`composer -n update`) can help if the manual STDIN declaration solution is not practical to implement.

You might need to delete the vendor folders that are generating the prompts, or to use `--prefer-source` for example, but that's another story.